# Send Telegram keyboard with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to send a Telegram keyboard with a bot to my account. I have followed [TelegramAPI](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) documentation but I am unable. I am using Python 2.7.

So far, this is what I have tried:

```
import requests

bot_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
chat_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
text = "Choose:"
reply_markup={"keyboard":[["Yes","No"],["Maybe"],["1","2","3"]],"one_time_keyboard":True}
data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': reply_markup}
url ="https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bot_token + "/sendMessage"

r = requests.get(url, data = data)
results = r.json()
print (results)
```

Python does not crash, but I get a fail response from Telegram API and I don't know why:

> {u'error_code': 400, u'ok': False, u'description': u"Bad Request:
>   can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"}

Any idea or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks, Ander.

Comment: Have you tried this: data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': str(reply_markup)}

Comment: @tashakori Thank you. I have tried it just know and I get the same Telegram error...

Comment: Or if there is any other method via requests to send keyboard please share...

Comment: Did you try "one_time_keyboard":"true" ? (Instead of "one_time_keyboard":True)

Comment: why don't you use well-implemented libraries like https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot ?

Comment: @newsha that does not work, I have tried it without positive results and getting same error message. However one_time_keyboard is an optional argument I can omit it. Omiting that argument also does not work.

Comment: @tashakori Thank you. I know that there are some libraries for Python, but that is not what I want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utilizing json library you can dump your keyboard object:

```
import requests, json

bot_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
chat_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
text = "Choose:"
reply_markup={"keyboard":[["Yes","No"],["Maybe"],["1","2","3"]],"one_time_keyboard":True}
data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
url ="https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bot_token + "/sendMessage"

r = requests.get(url, data = data)
results = r.json()
print (results)
```