# Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object Python

Tags: python, telegram

If copy/paste the print in the postman, works! but in Python give error

This is my code

```
array = '{"chat_id": "' + chat_id + '", "text": "Test Buttons", "reply_markup" : { "inline_keyboard" : [[ { "text" : "web", "url" :"google.es"}]]}}'    
data3  = json.loads(array)
    
print(array)
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage'
response = requests.get(url, params=data3)
print(response.json())
```

The error is

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': "Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"}
```

The print is

```
{"chat_id": "123XXX", "text": "Test Buttons", "reply_markup" : { "inline_keyboard" : [[ { "text" : "web", "url" :"google.es"}]]}}
```

Resolved
[Send Telegram keyboard with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149507/send-telegram-keyboard-with-python)

Comment: You might want to use triple backticks " ``` "in order to represent your code in an understandable manner.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Telegram API accepts string in the key `reply_markup`, so you can stringify the object before making a post request.

```
{
  "chat_id": -123456,
  "text": "Test",
  "reply_markup": JSON.stringify({
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [
        {
          "text": "Button2",
          "url": "https://www.example.com"
        },
        {
          "text": "Button2",
          "url": "https://www.example2.com"
        }
      ]
    ]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have used the wrong key for your second button's text, you should use `text`.

```json
{
  "chat_id": -123456,
  "text": "Test",
  "reply_markup": {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [
        {
          "text": "Button2",
          "url": "https://example.com"
        },
        {
          "text": "Button2",
          "url": "https://example2.com"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, when write the message i'worng, now is correct but el error continues

Comment: What error continues? Can you be specific?

Comment: Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object.   I edit the principal post

Comment: have you solved it? I have the same issue